# How to setup a Kubernetes secret using GoDaddy certs for Nginx Ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress

I'm struggling to setup a kubernetes secret using GoDaddy certs in order to use it with the Ingress Nginx controller in a Kubernetes cluster.

I know that GoDaddy isn't the go-to place for that but that's not on my hands...

Here what I tried (mainly based on this [github post](https://rammusxu.github.io/2019/11/06/k8s-Use-crt-and-key-in-Ingress/)):

I have a mail from GoDaddy with two files: `generated-csr.txt` and `generated-private-key.txt`.

Then I downloaded the cert package on GoDaddy's website (I took the "Apache" server type, as it's the recommended on for Nginx). The archive contains three files (with generated names): `xxxx.crt` and `xxxx.pem` (same content for both files, they represent the domain cert) and `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` (which is the intermediate cert).

Then I proceed to concat the domain cert and the intermediate cert (let's name it chain.crt) and tried to create a secret using these file with the following command:

```
kubectl create secret tls organization-tls --key generated-private-key.txt --cert chain.crt
```

And my struggle starts here, as it throw this error:

```
error: tls: failed to find any PEM data in key input
```

How can I fix this, or what I'm missing?

Sorry to bother with something trivial like this, but it's been two days and I'm really struggling to find proper documentation or example that works for the Ingress Nginx use case...

Any help or hint is really welcome, thanks a lot to you!

Comment: Do you run it in the same directory where your `key` is placed ? Are you sure your private key is in `.pem` format ? As you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets): "The public key certificate for --cert must be .PEM encoded (Base64-encoded DER format), and match the given private key for --key. The private key must be in what is commonly called PEM private key format, unencrypted. In both cases, the initial and the last lines from PEM (for example, --------BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -------END CERTIFICATE---- for a certificate) are not included."

Comment: Thanks mario for your time and effort.
The key wasn't format correctly as it was lacking a newline in the beginning of the file. So this particular problem is now resolved.
But due to the lack of documentation and effort from goDaddy for troubleshooting, I proposed to switch to another cert authority. I hope my journey will be less painful this way.
Thanks again !

Comment: Ran into this too. It's not actually missing a line, it is just wrongly encoded in UTF8 with BOM by GoDaddy where is should be encoded in simple UTF8 - thus removing a wrong byte at the beginning of the file, which screws up the base64 encoding. Properly encoding (see my answer) fixes the issue cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a Community Wiki answer, posted for better visibility, so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

As OP mentioned in comments, **the issue was solved by adding a new line in the beginning of the file**.

> "The key wasn't format correctly as it was lacking a newline in the
> beginning of the file. So this particular problem is now resolved."

Similar issue was also addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57614637/11714114).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is tricky but easy to fix.

The private key file given by GoDaddy is not properly encoded: it is encoded in UTF8 with BOM, so it starts with a byte that shouldn't be there. It is not understood by nginx ingress when ingesting the private key, and leads to the error.

The simple fix is to run the following command to properly encode the private key file:

```sh
iconv -c -f UTF8 -t ASCII generated-private-key.txt > generated-private-key-anssi.txt
```

And then you get the base64 private key as usual:

```sh
cat generated-private-key-anssi.txt | base64 -w 0
```

Now, the ingress properly gets the ssl certificate. In case you need to see the logs of the ingress to see how the CERT is processed, just list pods & logs in the `ingress-nginx` namespace.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue. This solution helped me create the tls without any problems. Thanks.